# boost::spirit: how to write a parser that parses 2 strings and have them 'combined' into only one?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I have a `qi::symbol<char, std::string>` `escapedDoubleQuote` that converts a double `""` into `\"`.

I try to use this into a more complex parser, and want the result still to be a single string. But didn't succeed. I tried with and without `qi::lexeme`, `qi::as_string` and `qi::as<std::string>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

struct escapedDoubleQuote_ : qi::symbols<char, std::string >
{
    escapedDoubleQuote_()
    {
        add("\"\"", "\\\"");
    }
} escapedDoubleQuote;

template<typename Iterator>
struct MyGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::string()>
{
    MyGrammar() : MyGrammar::base_type(escapedField)
    {
        subField = +(~qi::char_("\""));
        escapedField =
                qi::lexeme[  // or qi::as<std::string> ... both seems to do nothing.
                    subField
                    >> -(escapedDoubleQuote >> escapedField)
                ];
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> subField;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> escapedField;
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator_type;
    typedef MyGrammar<iterator_type> parser_type;
    parser_type parser;

    std::string input = "123\"\"456\"\"789";
    std::string output;
    iterator_type it = input.begin();
    bool parsed = parse(
            it,
            input.cend(),
            parser,
            output
    );

    if(parsed && it == input.end())
    {
        std::cout << output << std::endl;
        // expected: 123\"456\"789
        // actual  : \"789
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the end, I want to use the parser and have as output a single `std::string`. In the example `123\"\"456\"\"789` should output `123\"456\"789`.

---

Note: I know I can define the `escapedDoubleQuote` as `qi::symbols<char, std::vector<char> >` so that the result is achieved, but I want to understand if and how one can combine the strings.

Comment: When you are "assigning to a container from a value" and both the container and value are the same type, Spirit overwrites the container with the value (see "boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp" searching for `struct assign_to_container_from_value<Attribute, Attribute>`). If you use `vector<char>` in the `symbols` the types are not the same and another path is chosen reaching `void append_to_string(Attribute& attr, Iterator begin, Iterator end)` that does what you expect. [This hack](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97d43835f2dc1123) sidesteps the problem but may break something else.

Comment: @cv_and_he Yeah that looks overly hacky. I wouldn't touch the traits for builtin types, personally. Good spot on the include though /cc OP: take note!

Answer (score 0):

As @cv_and_he suggested, the "atomic" assignment behaviour stems from the transformation of the exposed attribute type (`std::vector<char>`) to `std::string`.

Specifically, it's about the declared attribute of `escapedField`, because when it is recursively invoked, it creates incompatible synthesized attribute combinations: `[std::vector<char>, std::string, std::string]`

If you can keep the attributes "equal" you fix the issue:

```
MyGrammar() : MyGrammar::base_type(start)
{
    subField     = +(~qi::char_("\""));
    escapedField = subField >> -(escapedDoubleQuote >> escapedField);
    start        = escapedField;
}

qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<char>()> subField, escapedField;
qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> start;
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62af41ffc27b8c39)**

(I removed `lexeme` because you had no skipper in the sample code, see [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965))

Comment: Notice that if you make the attribute of the `symbols` be `vector<char>` [it does not work again](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddffd0e029be59c1). So it only works when the attributes in each concatenation are different (in your case you have `vector<char>` that concatenates with the result of `string` and `vector<char>`, which is `string`). I think this is a bug, but I'm really not sure, it probably is needed in another use case.

Comment: @cv_and_he ooh. You're quite right. That's... Annoying. I'll leave it to the OP whether he wants to report this at the [spirit-general] mailing list.

Comment: hm, so there is no real solution (yet)? I do not understand the internals of boost::spirit enough for saying that it is a bug or intended behavior.

Comment: I'd say it is a lack of an expectable feature. Expectable because similar constellations of parser expressions (as opposed to rules or transformed sub-attributes) do work as expected.